# Select IN LINQ to entities with inner joins

Tags: c#, linq

I have the follow SQL query

```
SELECT ob.PK_OBJETIVO,
ev.NM_EVENTO,
ifi.QT_NOTA_IMPACTO,
imi.QT_NOTA_IMPACTO,
ire.QT_NOTA_IMPACTO,
(ifi.QT_NOTA_IMPACTO + imi.QT_NOTA_IMPACTO + ire.QT_NOTA_IMPACTO)/3 AS 
Media
FROM AVALIACAO_IMPACTO AS ai
INNER JOIN EVENTO AS EV ON ev.PK_EVENTO = ai.FK_AVALIACAO_IMPACTO_EVENTO
INNER JOIN OBJETIVO AS ob ON ob.PK_OBJETIVO = 
ai.FK_AVALIACAO_IMPACTO_OBJETIVO
INNER JOIN IMPACTO_FINANCEIRO AS ifi ON ifi.PK_IMPACTO_FINANCEIRO = 
ai.FK_AVALIACAO_IMPACTO_IMPACTO1
INNER JOIN IMPACTO_MISSAO AS imi ON IMI.PK_IMPACTO_MISSAO = 
AI.FK_AVALIACAO_IMPACTO_IMPACTO2
INNER JOIN IMPACTO_REPUTACAO AS IRE ON IRE.PK_IMPACTO_REPUTACAO = 
AI.FK_AVALIACAO_IMPACTO_IMPACTO3
WHERE ai.FK_AVALIACAO_IMPACTO_OBJETIVO IN
(SELECT OBJ.PK_OBJETIVO
 FROM OBJETIVO AS OBJ
 WHERE OBJ.FK_OBJETIVO_PROCESSO = 3)
```

I need to transform that query in a LINQ query, I tried that:

```
var queryImpactos = await _context.AvaliacaoImpacto
        .Where(e => _context.Objetivo.Select(o => 
o.ProcessoID).Contains(planoRiscos.Auditoria.ProcessoID))
        .Include(e => e.Evento).Include(e => e.Objetivo)
        .Include(e => e.ImpactoFinanceiro).Include(e => 
e.ImpactoMissao).Include(e => e.ImpactoReputacao).ToListAsync();
```

"`planoRiscos.Auditoria.ProcessoID`" returns what it takes, the number 3 of the pure SQL query, but the query result is returning all the records in the `AVALIACAO_IMPACTO` table, however I only need the records where a `FK_OBJETIVO` in `AVALIACAO_IMPACTO` exists within the `OBJETIVO` table, where the `FK_PROCESSO` in `OBJETIVO` is equal to the passed parameter (`planoRiscos.Auditoria.ProcessoID`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tip: whenever you need to convert SQL query to a LINQ query, make the query syntax your first choice.

Try this:

```
var queryImpactos = from ai in AVALIACAO_IMPACTO
                     join
ev in EVENTO on ai.FK_AVALIACAO_IMPACTO_EVENTO equals ev.PK_EVENTO
                     join ob in OBJETIVO on ai.FK_AVALIACAO_IMPACTO_OBJETIVO equals ob.PK_OBJETIVO
                     join ifi in IMPACTO_FINANCEIRO on ai.FK_AVALIACAO_IMPACTO_IMPACTO1 equals ifi.PK_IMPACTO_FINANCEIRO
                     join imi in IMPACTO_MISSAO on ai.FK_AVALIACAO_IMPACTO_IMPACTO2 equals imi.PK_IMPACTO_MISSAO
                     join IRE in IMPACTO_REPUTACAO on ai.FK_AVALIACAO_IMPACTO_IMPACTO3 equals IRE.PK_IMPACTO_REPUTACAO
                     where (from obj in OBJETIVO where obj.FK_OBJETIVO_PROCESSO == 3 select obj.PK_OBJETIVO).Contains(ai.FK_AVALIACAO_IMPACTO_OBJETIVO)
                     select new
                     {
                         ob.PK_OBJETIVO,
                         ev.NM_EVENTO,
                         QT_NOTA_IMPACTO1 = ifi.QT_NOTA_IMPACTO,
                         QT_NOTA_IMPACTO2 = imi.QT_NOTA_IMPACTO,
                         QT_NOTA_IMPACTO3 = IRE.QT_NOTA_IMPACTO,
                         Media = (ifi.QT_NOTA_IMPACTO + imi.QT_NOTA_IMPACTO + IRE.QT_NOTA_IMPACTO) / 3
                     };
```

Hope it's what you're looking for!